# How to send a post request that the user clicked on 1 of the buttons, and tell the server which one

Tags: html, node.js

The task is as follows. The user (Admin) checks the entries for correctness, and then clicks the accept or reject button. There are several such records (3, but I don't think it matters), each record has 2 such buttons. I tried to do something like

```
<form action="/admin" method="POST">
 <input type="button" name="button" value="accept" class="admin-buttons">
</form>
<form action="/admin" method="POST">
 <input type="button" name="button" value="decline" class="admin-buttons">
</form>
```

and then on server

```
app.post('/admin', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
if (req.body.button.value == 'accept'){} // changes on db
}
```

But it didn't work, so here I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error
The code below should work

```
app.post('/admin', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
if (req.body.button == 'accept'){} // changes on db
}
```

`req.body.button.value`  will give you undefined as its taking *button* to be an object

Next time console.log(req.body) for better debugging

And for your forms

```
<form action="/admin" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="button" value="accept" class="admin-buttons" hidden="">
 <input type="submit" name="button" value="accept" class="admin-buttons">
</form>
<form action="/admin" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="button" value="decline" class="admin-buttons" hidden="">
 <input type="submit" name="button" value="decline" class="admin-buttons">
</form>
```

Comment: I can't even get the post request from this form :(

Comment: @n33t I have updated the solution this should work __ remember to click the answer button if its solve your issues

Comment: much thx :):):):)